# how to create create event URL for voice app?

Tags: vonage

I tried to create a voice app  it demands:
Event URL 
https://exampe.com
Answer URL
http://example.com
 which domain do I need to use? Its matter which domain I use? they don't know my domain anyway.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer and event URLs are callback URLs (webhooks).
This means that when a voice call is created, and some events happens (such as ringing, user answered the call, user rejected the call, user not answering the call, etc.), the voice server will send a structured request to the callback URL you have provided.

From there, you can develop the logic the callback URL to decide what to do when those events happen, similar to the `onClickListener` on an Android App's button, if you are familiar with that.

The callback URL server should be hosted by you, implementing the exact same interface. You can refer to this page on what is expected.

https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/webhook-reference

As for the domain name, you can use whichever you want, as long as it is pointing to the correct route on your backend server.

Comment: thanks, on which event you recommend for creating an SMS autoresponder?

Comment: What would the use case for the SMS autoresponder be? This is a voice call, and in the middle of the call you want to send out SMS automatically?

Comment: hi, just want to create an Sms autoresponder to phone calls that I  miss.

Comment: Look for the `unanswered` or `rejected` events for calls that you didn't answer.

Comment: Yes, check out for `unanswered` or `rejected` events, but take note that sometimes if there is an answering machine like voice mail, it may still go through as `answered`, so you need to check whether it is a machine by specifying machine detection in your NCCO.